Simplify/shorten QUERY and FLATTEN formula for Google Sheets
I was working on a summary sheet recording different campaigns with its title, nsu, impression, and clicks. However, I have like 10+ columns for each platform. On the left side, I wanted to be able to create a summary where I could see the sum of the data for each campaign. So if lets say Mainstream title exists on each column, I wanted to see the sum data of it. But also, unique titles who have no similarity to other columns would also be listed into the summary.
Here's a sample sheet of my data.
I've tried to use the following formula but aside from the fact that it lead me to know here, It's obviously too time consuming. Can anyone recommend anything to do with this?
=QUERY({
  FLATTEN({E2:E, I2:I, M2:M, Q2:Q, U2:U, Y2:Y, AC2:AC, AG2:AG, AK2:AK, AO2:AO, AS:AS, AW:AW, BA:BA}),
  FLATTEN({F2:F, J2:J, N2:N, R2:R, V2:V, Z2:Z, AD2:AD, AH2:AH, AL2:AL, AP2:AP, AT2:AT, AX2:AX, BB2:BB}),
  FLATTEN({G2:G, K2:K, O2:O, S2:S, W2:W, AA2:AA, AE2:AE, AI2:AI, AM2:AM, AQ2:AQ, AU2:AU, AY2:AY, BC2:BC}),
  FLATTEN({H2:H, L2:L, P2:P, T2:T, X2:X, AB2:AB, AF2:AF, AJ2:AJ, AN2:AN, AR2:AR, AV2:AV, AZ2:AZ, BD2:BD})
}, "SELECT Col1, SUM(Col2), SUM(Col3), SUM(Col4) WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL GROUP BY Col1", 1)



Here's one approach you may test out:
=query(
       let(Λ,tocol(,1),reduce(Λ,sequence(14,1,1,4),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,let(Σ,choosecols(E3:BH,sequence(4,1,c)),ifna(filter(Σ,index(Σ,,1)<>""),Λ)))))),
  "select Col1, sum(Col2), sum(Col3), sum(Col4) group by Col1 label sum(Col2) '',sum(Col3) '',sum(Col4) ''")



Hello. Thank you for answering my question but unfortunately this formula does not presents the results I'm aiming for. I was hoping to see each campaign title to be sorted out based on their title and sum up each of their data on each column.

Can you cite one or two examples with their ideal output numbers so that we get a picture of your expected scenario?!

It was actually close to what Harun24hr did but I was hoping to see those campaign title who were distinct/appeared only once to be listed. Harun manage to generate Campaign titles and the sum of their data, but some of my campaigns who have distinct title for example on column Y:AB were not listed since they only appeared once.

I don't know if it's impossible, but I would like to find a way to organize these. Maybe I can use a filter to determine the exact campaign. I sucked with formulas but am pretty much willing to learn so I have been trying to ask and understand everything.

You need nested FILTER() then sum. I have used MAKEARRAY() formula to make it dynamic spill array formula. Try-
=LET(x,UNIQUE(TOCOL(E3:E,1)),
HSTACK(x,MAKEARRAY(ROWS(x),3,LAMBDA(r,c,SUM(FILTER(FILTER(F3:BH,F2:BH2=INDEX(B2:D2,1,c)),E3:E=INDEX(x,r,1)))))))



Hi! I noticed this formula only summarizes those campaigns that have existed in each column. But how about those unique campaigns that only exist as one/unique from the others?

Some examples of these 'Unique campaigns' were the campaign titles listed from Y:AB
